# Why is Faile so much faster than The Simple Chess Program (TSCP)? (Chess engine optimization)

Tags: c, optimization, chess

I hope this isn't too much of an arbitrary question, but I have been looking through the source codes of Faile and TSCP and I have been playing them against each other. As far as I can see the engines have a lot in common, yet Faile searches ~1.3 million nodes per second while TSCP searches only 300k nodes per second.

The source code for faile can be found here: http://faile.sourceforge.net/download.php. TSCP source code can be found here: http://www.tckerrigan.com/Chess/TSCP.

After looking through them I see some similarities: both use an array board representation (although Faile uses a 144 size board), both use a alpha beta search with some sort of transposition table, both have very similar evaluate functions. The main difference I can find is that Faile uses a redundant representation of the board by also having arrays of the piece locations. This means that when the moves are generated (by very similar functions for both programs), Faile has to for loop through fewer bad pieces, while maintaining this array costs considerably fewer resources.

My question is: why is there a 4x difference in the speed of these two programs? Also, why does Faile consistently beat TSCP (I estimate about a ~200 ELO difference just by watching their moves)? For the latter, it seems to be because Faile is searching several plies deeper.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TSCP has not hash tables (-75 ELO).
TSCP has not Killers moves for ordering (-50 ELO).
TSCP has not null move (-100 ELO).
TSCP has a bad attack function design (-25 ELO).

In these 4 things you have about a difference of 250 points ELO. This will increase the number of nodes per second but you can not compare nodes per second on different engines as programmers can use a different interpretation of what is a node.

Answer (score 8):

**Short answer:** TSCP is very simple (as you can guess from its name). Faile is more advanced, some time was spent by developers to optimize it. So it is just reasonable for Faile to be faster, which means also deeper search and higher ELO.

**Long answer:** As far as I remember, the most important part of the program, using alpha beta search (part which influences performance the most), is move generator. TSCP's move generator does not generate moves in any particular order. Faile's generator (as you noticed), uses piece list, which is sorted in order of decreasing piece value. This means it generates more important moves first. This allows alpha-beta pruning to cut more unneeded moves and makes search tree less branchy. And less branchy tree may be deeper and still have the same number of nodes, which allows deeper search.

Here is a very simplified example how the order of moves allows faster search. Suppose, last white's move was silly - they moved some piece to unprotected position. If we find some black's move that removes this piece, we can ignore all other, not yet estimated moves and return back to processing white's move list. Queen controls much more space than a pawn, so it has more chances to remove this piece, so if we look at queen's moves first, we can more likely skip more unneeded moves.

I didn't compare other parts of these programs. But most likely, Faile optimizes them better as well. Things like alpha-beta algorithm itself, variable depth of the search tree, static position analysis may be also optimized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can share some research I did into it in the meantime. I think I found that perhaps the biggest reason, while what you said is a good reason, is that while it seems at first TSCP is using transposition tables, it actually isn't. It creates a Zobrist key but only uses it for draw by repetition. This means that it is potentially analyzing some positions many times. From what I've read, transposition tables can compose a 3-4x performance increase.